# Linkedlist recursive method

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list, stack-overflow

I'm trying to write a recursive method that prints a linked list in reverse but I get a stackoverflow error. The method should terminate when the last element of the array has been reached, and return control to the method that called it, and then that method will print and return to the one that called it and so forth.

```
public void print(Node node){
    if(node.next != null)
       print(node.next);

    System.out.println(" " + node.value + " ");
}
```

Comment: It looks like your list is either (1) too long, or (2) circular.

Comment: You don't describe the topology of your linked list.  Is it circular or not? Do you have a `tail` or `head` reference that we could (potentially) use to stop your iteration?

Comment: There is a head reference. It's a singly linked list

Comment: I think the problem is my memory is too small. Any advice?

Comment: If the problem is memory, you need to increase the stack space. Look at the options for whatever you are using to run the program.

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Convert your code into

```
public void print(Node node){
   System.out.println(" " + node.value + " "); 
 if(node.next != null)
       print(node.next);   

}
```

1. If it still fails with an exception , it means you have a cyclic linked list
2. If it does not fail, it means  you are filling up the default memory heap assigned to your application. You can try increasing the heap size to see if it resolves the problems

Once you figure out the issue, you can restore the original code.If you want info on how to increase heap size, check out this link

[Increase heap size in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565388/increase-heap-size-in-java)

Comment: This prints first, not last.  The idea is to print things in reverse order; if you print before you recurse, you're printing them in insertion order.

Comment: Yes I understand that. I am trying to debug if you have a circular linked list or if you are just running out of memory